# Hover Animation Color Switch

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a color switch with a hover but the problem I'm encountering is that the text (closed within a span) is in a list item and the only way I can achieve the effect is if I hover over the word but I want it to switch when I hover over the whole list item element.

```css
span {
color: orange;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
font-weight: 200;
}

ul {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;;
}

li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
padding: 10px 10px;
font-size: 30px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
font-weight: 300;
border-right: 1px;
border-left: 1px;
}

#ot {
border-top: 1px solid orange;
border-bottom: 1px;
border-left: 1px solid orange;
}

#ob {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-top: 1px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
color: 
}

#black:hover {
color: black;
}

#ot:hover {
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
color: orange;
}

#ob:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
border-right: 1px solid orange;
color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="ot">high <span id="black">Park</span></li>
  <li id="ob">the <span id="black">Beach</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target `span` while hovering over **`#ob`**, **`#ot`**. Like:

```
#ob:hover #black {
  color: black;
}

#ot:hover #black {
  color: black;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
span {
color: orange;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
font-weight: 200;
}

ul {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;;
}

li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
padding: 10px 10px;
font-size: 30px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
font-weight: 300;
border-right: 1px;
border-left: 1px;
}

#ot {
border-top: 1px solid orange;
border-bottom: 1px;
border-left: 1px solid orange;
}

#ob {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-top: 1px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
color: 
}

#black:hover {
color: black;
}

#ot:hover {
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
color: orange;
}

#ob:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
border-right: 1px solid orange;
color: orange;
}

#ob:hover #black {
  color: black;
}

#ot:hover #black {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="ot">high <span id="black">Park</span></li>
  <li id="ob">the <span id="black">Beach</span></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```css
span {
color: orange;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
font-weight: 200;
}

ul {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;;
}

li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-flex;
padding: 10px 10px;
font-size: 30px;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
font-weight: 300;
border-right: 1px;
border-left: 1px;
}

#ot {
border-top: 1px solid orange;
border-bottom: 1px;
border-left: 1px solid orange;
}

#ob {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-top: 1px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
color: 
}

#ot:hover #black,
#ob:hover #black {
color: black;
}

#ot:hover {
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
color: orange;
}

#ob:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
border-right: 1px solid orange;
color: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="ot">high <span id="black">Park</span></li>
  <li id="ob">the <span id="black">Beach</span></li>
</ul>
```